# How can I import lodash library in my Vanilla JS file

Tags: import, module, lodash

I have installed the "lodash" using "npm install --save lodash" and imported in my JS file.My intention is to Deep clone of an Object and found that Lodash is the library which solve this problem. My HTML and JS files are as follows.

My HTML file is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <script type="module" src="scripts.js" ></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file (scripts.js) is as follows:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

let userOne = {
 name: "Siju",
 userFunction:function(){
  return this.name;
 } 
};
 
// Deep Copy: Start
let userTwo=_.cloneDeep(userOne);
// Deep Copy: End

userTwo.name="Johnson";
userTwo.userFunction=function(){ return this.name.length }

console.log(userOne.name);
console.log(userTwo.name);
console.log(userOne.userFunction());
console.log(userTwo.userFunction());
```

But i am getting following errors.

Error1: (When use: import _ from 'lodash';)
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Error2: (When use: import _ from './node_modules/lodash';)
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I have spend lot of time on this and did'nt get any suitable solution. I am really frustrated on this issue because it is a silly issue but did'nt get any proper fix in the internet. Most of the explanation is seems to be with so many dependency fixes and all. But no any fixes are worked for me. So anyone can be come up with simple and proper fix for this. Thank You Very Much in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://lodash.com/ and download the entire .js file into your current project folder and then include the following line in your HTML body paragraph.

`<script src="lodash.js"> </script>`

And then import it at the top of your JavaScript file in which you would like to use it.

`import _ from 'lodash'`

Comment: Hi @Dinesh kumar, Thank You for your answer. Actually I have tried a CDN version and it works fine. But i would like to work it with NPM and import lodash in to my JS file. Hopes you understand my approach. Some of the JS ecosystems are still misterios and we need to spend larger amount of time to understand even a silly things. My this issue is an example. Actually i was spending 2 days for this and still i did'nt get an answer. Thats a big disadvantages of JS and Its Ecosystems. Anyway, Thank You for your Answer.

Comment: Then, if you are working on node js project, only then you can install lodash in you project by `npm install lodash` and import lodash as `import _ from 'lodash'`

Comment: I am not much very good at NodeJS. So let me ask, whats the difference between Node JS project and HTML project. How can i setup a NodeJS project, can you share any website for this. I was trying the following documentation on my issue: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was like you commented spending time try to find the solution. Using CDN it works.  Using Vite it works. But using only npm it didn´t work.
I used the `lodash-es` version (that is the version with ESModules).
Finally the solution was that the import statament should be:

```
import _ from '/node_modules/lodash-es/lodash.js';
```

That is because when you install it using `npm i --save lodash-es`, inside the folder `node_modules/lodash-es/` is the `lodash.js` file that contains the export declarations of all functions of lodash-es library.

[image]

I tested your code, just changing the import statement and here is the result:

[image]